# How to create a module view and stick it onto a position in asp.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Sory about my question, I am brand new to MVC 4 Razor, it's different from Asp.NET Web form.

Look like joomla, and other web languague, how can i create a "module", eg: "news, ads, counter" and stick it to asp.NET page.

I have a layout.cshtml in share folder, i think it's "Master Page" (like Master Page in Asp.NET webform)

How can i create some positions in that layout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create partial views or controller/actions that return a partial.

**Partial Views**

First create a partial view (which is a razor view without boilerplate markup like doctype, html and body elements.

To use a partial view in Razor:

```
@Html.Partial("name-of-partial-view", model-for-the-partial-view)
```

**Actions returning a partial**

To have a controller create a partial for you, create an action like this:

```
public DemoController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]  // Optional attribute, making this action invisible to the routing system
    public ActionResult Demonstration(string someparam)
    {
        // Do something with someparam to get information to display

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

You'll need to create a partial view to be returned from this action. (As before, a partial doesn't have the boilrplate markup like doctype, html and body.)

And to call it from Razor:

```
@Html.Action("Demonstration", "Demo", new { someparam = "something" });
```

If you want this partial on every page, put it somewhere in your layout page.

Comment: Ohh yes, thank you very much !

i found it on google but not sure, just ask for clear